# Office-JS Excel functionalities (named range, style, union, etc)

Tags: excel, vsto, office365, office-js

I'm looking to port an existing VSTO application to an Office 365 web addin.

So far, many of the features I need are available as-of Excel API v1.1. But there are a few that I can't seem to find.

1. Creating a named range

   - `Workbook.Names.Add(name, range)`;
2. Deleting a named range

   - `NamedRange.Delete();`
3. Resizing a ListObject

   - `ListObject.Resize(range);`
   - I can work around this by converting the table to a range, and recreating the table again. But I lose any existing formatting/conditional formatting
4. Set Range's style

   - `Range.Style = "Accent1";`
5. Group Range rows

   - `Range.Rows.Group();`
6. Indent Range

   - `Range.InsertIndent(indentAmount);`
7. Union of 2 ranges

   - `Application.union(range1, range2);`
   - Usage: highlighting 2-or-more non-contiguous ranges

Of all the above functionalities, I need creating/deleting named ranges the most.

I need workbooks generated by the OfficeJS addin to be readable by my VSTO addin, and vice-versa. Last time I checked, names added via `document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync()` (as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38469410/how-to-name-and-reference-an-excel-range-using-office-js)) are not accessible in VSTO.

Was wondering if these features are buried somewhere in the API that I've missed. If not, where do I go from here?

Comment: `Last time I checked, names added via document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync() (as proposed here) are not accessible in VSTO.` The code is creating a bind object which is concepcion in Office add-in(apps for Office). You can submit the feedback [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com) if you have any requirement or good idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback.
Feel free to submit further feature requests for our APIs at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/ and we will consider them for future API releases.

-Philip, Developer on the Microsoft Office Extensibility team